# Error importing SVN report to git using svn2git

Tags: svn2git

I get the following error when importing an SVN repository to git with svn2git:

`fatal: EOF in data (285 bytes remaining)`

Does anyone know what this error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a segmentation fault, there is a branch/tag/ in your repository that is causing it to core.

To get the core files you will need to enable cores:
Uncomment this line in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
soft  core  unlimited
```

Run svn2git, it may take up to 2 hours to get the segmentation fault. Install gdb:

```
yum install gdb
```

Analyse the core:

```
gdb svn2git/svn-all-fast-export core.NNNN
```

Get a back trace, type:

```
bt
```

You should see the branch/tag which caused problems in the back trace. Exclude the branch from processing by updating your ruleset:

```
match /branches/broken_branch_name
end match
```

See issue opened with owner of svn2git here:
https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git/issues/26

Or even easier, `pstack <pid of svn2git>` and you will see where it is stuck, then Ctrl + C, add the dud branch to your rule set and start svn2git again.